# How can I draw a single pixel?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, graphics

Hey,
Like in title can someone answer this "simple" question? I need draw line using only method Setpixel but have no idea how to do single pixel on Form. Yeah it's howework.

Thanks:)

Comment: What is the purpose of drawing the pixel? Homework?

Comment: This depends on where you want to draw the pixel.  On a form or button?  Somewhere else?  The answer can be very different - need more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your form, look into the OnPaint method, and the capabilities of the supplied Graphics object.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
   e.Graphics...
}
```

--

No need to involve Bitmaps and all that - single line call in .NET

```
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.ControlDark, xLoc, yLoc, 1, 1);
```

Comment: the Graphics object does not have a method for drawing a single pixel

Comment: shall i use something like bitmap.Setpixel(); ?

Answer (score 1):

This will draw you a single Black pixel:

```
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle (Brushes.Black , new Rectangle(50, 50, 1, 1));
    }
```

Comment: Do not use 'using'.  You are forcing the disposal of a Graphics object you didn't create, and will explode if someone/thing uses e.Graphics.DoSomething(...) subsequently